# Will dmesg always report file system read errors?

Tags: rsync, dmesg, smartctl

OS is Debian 10.

Smartctl reports a bad block on a hard drive.

Rsync has been regularly doing backups to a backup drive.

dmesg has not reported any errors.

Does that mean the data on the backup drive is intact?

Will dmesg always report read errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will dmesg always report file system read errors?

Short answer, yes, absolutely.

Long answer: even before the filesystem driver, there's a block layer which absolutely does report IO errors. If you've seen nothing so far, it most likely means your data is safe.

Then, the way modern drives work, some of their errors are not fatal - for instance, there's this thing called "reallocation" - i.e. when the firmware sees that a particular sector read/write parameters are beyond normal/satisfactory, it's going to be replaced with a healthy one which will be totally transparent to you.